# DecimalFormat doesn't work on android 7

Tags: android, formatting, decimalformat

I have a method that converts numeric values to a formatted string. It works well, but only on versions less than android 7. On Android 7 and above it is ignored.

```
public static String printableSumSeparators(double sum, String format) {
    DecimalFormatSymbols dfSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    dfSymbols.setDecimalSeparator(COMMA_SEPARATOR);
    dfSymbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(format, dfSymbols);
    df.setGroupingUsed(true);
    return df.format(sum);
}
```

Where COMMA_SEPARATOR = ',';
The input of the method is fed with 2 parameters, the number itself for the conversion and the format in the form: ##.0#
Example:
Input: 500000
Output: 500 000
But on the android 7 it does not work and the number is not formatted
**Question: How to fix this bug and make it work on the latest version of android**

Comment: you want output 500 000?

Comment: Yes that's right

Answer (score 2):

On the latest versions of android you also need to **setGroupingSize**. Like this:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols dfSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
dfSymbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
dfSymbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(format, dfSymbols);
df.setGroupingSize(3);
df.setGroupingUsed(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe below code is useful for you, because its work like separating the decimal value using comma's.

```
protected String getCommaSeparated(String s)
{
    try
    {
        if (s.length() > 0)
        {
           s =
           customFormat("##,##,##0",Double.parseDouble(s.toString().replace(",","")));
            if(s.length() > 0)
            {
                return s;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return s;
}  

public String customFormat(String pattern, double value)
{
    DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
    String output = myFormatter.format(value);
    return output;
}
```